# Analyze video content, create an index on (with a search engine?)

Tags: video, indexing, content-indexing

How can I create an Index on thousands of video files? 
Analyze the audio track of a video file and write this somewher, like a tag.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad, I am afraid. The only answer I can give you would be vague. How? Depending on what are these files and how granular your indexing should be, you have few choices.

1. By file name, compression method, stream properties. The obvious one and fairly easy to implement. Especially if these files (which I doubt) support [MPEG-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-7).
2. By analyzing the contents. It is hard. Very, very hard. It would require adopting technique known as [Computer Vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision). Possible solutions would involve [Machine Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning), probably [Neural Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network). Fairly impossible for single (even genius) programmer.

Answer (score 0):

By traversing the directory structure and obtaining information about the streams from it's container format. Without knowing OS and programming language of choice, I cannot be more specific.